# c recursive function to check if a string is palindrome

Tags: c, function, recursion, c-strings, palindrome

I am doing a project in C programming language and one of the tasks require me to recursively check if a string is a palindrome. I wrote some code but I don't get correct output. Here are some rules governing the task:

1. If the string is a palindrome, return 1, otherwise return 0.
2. If the string is empty return 1.
   Here is the code I used:

```
int is_palindrome(char *s)
{
    int len;

    len = strlen(s);
    if (len == 0 || len == 1)
        return (0);

    if (*s != s[len - 1])
        return (1);

    return is_palindrome(s + 1);
}
```

and here is my driver code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * main - check the code
 *
 * Return: Always 0.
 */
int main(void)
{
    int r;

    r = is_palindrome("level");
    printf("%d\n", r);
    r = is_palindrome("redder");
    printf("%d\n", r);
    r = is_palindrome("test");
    printf("%d\n", r);
    r = is_palindrome("step on no pets");
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return (0);
}
```

**NB: All declarations are in the main.h file**

The output I get is 1 all through, the code works fine to an extent, as I used the principle of if first character is same as last character, it is a palindrome. But I want it to work for all cases like the case of even-numbered strings.

How should I fix the code to work properly? Thank you

Comment: "If the string is empty return 1" That does not match `if (len == 0 || len == 1)  return (0);`

Comment: You need to take care about removing the last character from the test in your recursive calls. Otherwise you will compare all characters only with the last one. For this purpose you could pass the length to your function and decrement by 2 for each recursive call.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the function signature of the `is_palindrome` function?

Comment: Is the function required to work with string literals? If not, you could replace the last character with a `\0` in each step and don't need to pass a length parameter. That will not work with string literals.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive call of the function

```
return is_palindrome(s + 1);
```

results in checking whether all characters in a string are equal to the last character due to this statement

```
if (*s != s[len - 1])
```

ALso this if statement

```
if (len == 0 || len == 1)
    return (0);
```

contradicts the description of the assignment because for empty strings the function shall return `1`.

You could write for example introducing a helper function

```
int is_palindrome_rec( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    return ( n < 2 ) || ( s[0] == s[n-1] && is_palindrome_rec( s + 1, n - 2 ) );
}

int is_palindrome( const char *s)
{
    return is_palindrome_rec( s, strlen( s ) );
}
```

Another way is to use a static variable within the function as shown below in the  demonstration program.  Though such an approach is inefficient due to calling the function `strlen` in each recursive call. However it is always useful to bear in mind alternative approaches.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrome( const char *s )
{
    static size_t offset = 0;

    size_t n = strlen( s );

    if ( n - offset < 2 ) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( s[offset] != s[n - offset - 1] )
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        ++offset;
        int result = is_palindrome( s );
        --offset;

        return result;
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *s = "1";

    printf( "is_palindrome( \"%s\" ) is %s\n",
        s, is_palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "11";

    printf( "is_palindrome( \"%s\" ) is %s\n",
        s, is_palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "121";

    printf( "is_palindrome( \"%s\" ) is %s\n",
        s, is_palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "122";

    printf( "is_palindrome( \"%s\" ) is %s\n",
        s, is_palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

The program output is

```
is_palindrome( "1" ) is true
is_palindrome( "11" ) is true
is_palindrome( "121" ) is true
is_palindrome( "122" ) is false
```

Comment: Instead of writing code that looks like an IOCCC competitor, you could just subtract -1 from the initial strlen call. Also I benchmarked it and your one-liner can't get optimized into inlined tail call by gcc -O3. Likely caused by gcc failing to untangle the logical operators. So it is both unreadable and inefficient, but hey it's on one line... lets teach newbies to write code like that.

Comment: @Lundin If the code of the first two functions is unreadable for you you should visit curces for beginners. And this statement return is_palindrome_rec( s, strlen( s ) - 1 ); can result in undefined behavior if the passed string is empty.

Comment: It's not just me who thinks it is unreadable, it is also gcc. Recursion should obviously be avoided like the plague in real programs, but when you use it, you have to make sure it can get unrolled by tail call optimization. gcc cannot do this with your first function and the cause is likely the use of logical operators over if/else.

Comment: Benchmark https://godbolt.org/z/jE8v6rvde. All I did was to get rid of the logical operators.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nice `is_palindrome_rec( )`.

Comment: You can use the `static` values to avoid calling `strlen` at each call. I left an example below

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: `if (*s != s[len - 1]) return (1);` doesn't make any sense, it should return zero (false).

Problem 2: `return is_palindrome(s + 1);` only iterates from the front, you need to iterate from the back as well.

You can fix it by passing the length as well. You could move the strlen call outside the recursion (which also improves performance) and pass the length along.

However, this turns much more easy and readable to implement if you just pass along a pointer to the first and last letter, then increment/decrement until the pointers meet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool check_palindrome (const char* start, const char* end)
{
   if(start >= end)     // pointers have met in the middle without differences detected
     return true;
   if (*start != *end)  // values differ at some point, stop here
     return false;

   return check_palindrome(start+1, end-1);
}

bool is_palindrome (const char *s)
{
    size_t length = strlen(s);
    if(length == 0)
      return true;
    return check_palindrome (s, s+length-1);
}

int main(void) 
{
  printf("%d\n", is_palindrome("level"));
  printf("%d\n", is_palindrome("redder"));
  printf("%d\n", is_palindrome("test"));
}
```

Please also note that recursion fills absolutely no purpose here, a loop is always better. In this specific case, it was easy to implement the recursion as "tail call", but that's not always the case. And when it isn't, recursion is always needlessly dangerous and slow for absolutely nothing gained.

Benchmarking on gcc 13.1 x86_64 `-O3`, note the absence of recursive calls in the machine code:

```
is_palindrome:
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        call    strlen
        xor     edx, edx
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L1
        lea     rax, [rbx-1+rax]
        cmp     rbx, rax
        jb      .L3
        jmp     .L5
.L11:
        sub     rax, 1
        add     rbx, 1
        cmp     rbx, rax
        jnb     .L5
.L3:
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rax]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx], cl
        je      .L11
        xor     edx, edx
.L1:
        mov     eax, edx
        pop     rbx
        ret
.L5:
        mov     edx, 1
        pop     rbx
        mov     eax, edx
        ret
```

Comment: If I may, passing `s + length` as `end` (and changing the function accordingly), would avoid it pointing to the element *before* `start` when a `""` is passed, but that's nitpicking and I'm biased.

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah this can be improved with extra error handling as well and handling upper/lower case etc. I just wanted it as readable as possible.

Comment: @Lundin As I already pointed out in another comment this statement return check_palindrome (s, s+length-1); can invoke undefined behavior for empty strings.

Comment: Fine, fixed, lets not leave _anything_ as an exercise to the OP. I added an error check for empty strings. Note how I did not drag the error checking into the recursive function, since that would make the code less readable and possibly add extra branching.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure if an empty string should count as a palindrome - there are no letters.

Comment: A nice attribute of `is_palindrome(const char *s)` is the ability to change code in handing the `is_palindrome("")` case.  Such corner cases are often contentious as to the best return value.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your program.

First of all, your return values for palindromes are inversed.

```c
int is_palindrome(char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len == 0 || len == 1)
        return 1;  // Empty string or 1char string are treated as palindromes

    if (*s != s[len - 1])
        return 0;  // If they do not match, no palindrome.

    // Not sure yet, lets look into the other characters.
    return is_palindrome(s + 1);
}
```

Additionally, you advance to the next character at the start of the string but you keep the last character untouched.
There are 2 options to solve that. Both have different advantages and drawbacks.

Variant 1: Pass length parameter:

```c
int is_palindrome(char *s, size_t len)
{
    if (len == 0 || len == 1)
        return 1;  // Empty string or 1char string are treated as palindromes

    if (*s != s[len - 1])
        return 0;  // If they do not match, no palindrome.

    // Not sure yet, lets look into the other characters.
    return is_palindrome(s+1, len-2);
}

int main(void)
{
    int r;
    char *string;

    string = "level";
    r = is_palindrome(string, strlen(string));
    printf("%d\n", r);

    string = "redder";
    r = is_palindrome(string, strlen(string));
    printf("%d\n", r);

    string = "test";
    r = is_palindrome(string, strlen(string));
    printf("%d\n", r);

    string = "step on no pets";
    r = is_palindrome(string, strlen(string));
    printf("%d\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

This requires changing the signature of your function. Depending on your assignment that might not be allowed.

Variant 2: Remove last character:

```c
int is_palindrome(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    if (len == 0 || len == 1)
        return 1;  // Empty string or 1char string are treated as palindromes

    if (*s != s[len - 1])
        return 0;  // If they do not match, no palindrome.

    // Not sure yet, lets look into the other characters.
    s[len-1] = 0; //Chop last character
    return is_palindrome(s+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int r;
    char string[100];

    strcpy(string,"level");
    r = is_palindrome(string);
    printf("%d\n", r);

    strcpy(string,"redder");
    r = is_palindrome(string);
    printf("%d\n", r);

    strcpy(string,"test");
    r = is_palindrome(string);
    printf("%d\n", r);

    strcpy(string,"step on no pets");
    r = is_palindrome(string);
    printf("%d\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

This variant requires that you can modify the passed string argument. That is not allowed for string literals.

Comment: Variant 2 is just horribly inefficient and shouldn't be shown to beginners. It's bad enough to expose beginners to recursion in the first place.

Comment: I know that it is not efficient. If efficiency is an issue, recursion is the wrong solution anyway. That is just for learning purposes.

Comment: And that's kind of why I hate the existence of recursion in beginner classes. No teacher can _ever_ give a rationale _why_ they teach recursion. The so-called rationale is always "we teach recursion for learning purposes". Never "we teach recursion for increased readability, performance or program safety" since that would be a lie.

Comment: That's so true...

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the truth values reversed and you always compare with the last character in the string. Here is a working version:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int Palindromic1(const char s[], int len)
{
    int result;

    if (len <= 1) {
        result = 1;
    } else if (toupper(s[0]) != toupper(s[len - 1])) {
        result = 0;
    } else {
        result = Palindromic1(s + 1, len - 2);
    }
    return result;
}


int Palindromic(const char s[])
{
    return Palindromic1(s, strlen(s));
}


int main(void)
{
    assert(Palindromic(""));
    assert(Palindromic("a"));
    assert(Palindromic("aba"));
    assert(! Palindromic("abb"));
    assert(Palindromic("abba"));
    assert(! Palindromic("abab"));
    assert(Palindromic("Able was I ere I saw Elba"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is already clear that at each call the *end* of the string must be back by 1.
You should also not change the string because it can be a literal like in `is_palindrome("a thing")`. And anyway you should not alter the string: it can be needed elsewhere in the original form, as the caller just want to know if the string is or is not palindrome anyway.

Sure, recursion here is a waste, but it is a common assignment to write this using recursion because it is simple and illustrative.

In the following lines I will try to show why. And also left complete examples.

#### an iterative version

```
int isPal(const char* str)
{
    char*  p    = (char*)str;
    size_t size = 0;
    while (*p++ != 0)++ size;  // strlen
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size / 2; i += 1)
        if (*(str + i) != *(str + size - i - 1))
            return 0;  // false
    return 1; // all equal: palindrome
}
```

Here

- the `while` loop computes the size so no need for `string.h`
- the `for` loop zoom into the string to see if it is a palindrome.

#### a recursive version

If is possible to change the signature, we can pass the initial size as parameter

```
int isPal_r(const char* str, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
    if (*str != *(str + size - 1)) return 0; 
    return isPal_r(str + 1, size - 2);  // try inner string
}
```

Here we see how the `while` loop goes away, since the `size` is passed at 1st call.
And how the `for` loop goes away, substituted by recursive calls.
This is why this palindrome check thing, and the inevitable factorial evaluation, are often present as recursion is introduced.

#### how to not change the signature

A possible way of doing this is by using 2 `static` values:

- no change in the original string
- no need of a second parameter
- no need to call `strlen` or compute the size at each call
- a way to *reset* the function so it can be re-used in the same program

```
int is_Pal(const char* str)
{
    static char first = 1;
    static long size  = 0;
    if (first != 0)
    {
        const char* p = str;
        while (*p++ != 0) ++size;  // strlen
        first = 0; // now false
    }
    else
        size -= 2;

    if (size < 2)
    {   first = 1, size = 0;  // reset
        return 1;             // trivial
    }

    if (*str != *(str + size - 1))
    {   first = 1, size = 0;  // reset
        return 0;
    }
    return is_Pal(str + 1);  // try inner string
}
```

This one does the trick.

#### a test

```
SO C> p 1 11 axa "" abcdxba "123454321 1221 123454321"
     6 arguments.
     Return 1 for a palindrome, or 0


string is "1"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "11"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "axa"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is ""
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "abcdxba"
     isPal_r() returned 0

string is "123454321 1221 123454321"
     isPal_r() returned 1
 
SO C> p

Please enter strings on the command line: Usage: program str1 str2 ...

SO C>
```

#### the source code for this test

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  is_Pal(const char*);
void test_isPal(const char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "\nPlease enter strings on the command line: "
            "Usage: program "
            "str1 str2 ...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "     %d arguments.\n     Return 1 for a "
        "palindrome, or 0\n\n",
        argc - 1);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        test_isPal(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

void test_isPal(const char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) return;
    fprintf(stderr, "\nstring is \"%s\"\n", str);
    char*  p    = (char*)str;
    int res = is_Pal(str);
    fprintf(stderr, "     isPal_r() returned %d\n", res);
}

int is_Pal(const char* str)
{
    static char first = 1;
    static long size  = 0;
    if (first != 0)
    {
        const char* p = str;
        while (*p++ != 0) ++size;  // strlen
        first = 0; // now false
    }
    else
        size -= 2;

    if (size < 2)
    {
        first = 1, size = 0;  // reset
        return 1;             // trivial
    }

    if (*str != *(str + size - 1))
    {
        first = 1, size = 0;  // reset
        return 0;
    }
    return is_Pal(str + 1);  // try inner string
}
```